# How to load constants dynamically in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table alertTypes. On a callback I need to access this table data.Every hour, website receives more than 1k hits from these callbacks.  This makes a lot of db queries which I want to reduce. How can be these alertTypes records made global in constants.php?

Comment: Do the alertTypes _ever_ change?  What is this data?  How big is it?  Might you make a file in config, then use `$autoload['config']` in autoload.php?

Comment: Yeah I considered that for a while but did not find any working solution for that. Help me if you've any idea about this. 
there are only 8-10 records but needs to be from database.

Comment: Sorry, not at my computer any more.  When does this data need to be updated? Every page load?  You want to cache it? Memoize it?

Comment: situation is 
1. I keep receiving events from a server. These are like entering office or leaving office based on camera clicks.
2. There are alerts stored in system. Such as when employee1 logs in the event is sent from the server. If this has been stored in system, It is compared to event received from server.  So for comparision I dont want db query again and again. I want this data in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for this. What I did, I created a pre controller (a type of HOOKS in codeigniter ) which loads all the data needed for the processing. It reduces db queries significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Constants are like variables except that once they are defined they cannot be changed or undefined. You can save into file